# Update user field based on the selected lookup value

Tags: column, people-picker

I need to update a user field based on the value selected from a lookup column.

Ex:

I have a lookup column with Location details. When I select a location the corresponding manager name gets populated in the user field

Comment: Please add more details to your question, what are you trying to do? How? Where? With what tooling?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your brief question , You need to create a cascading dropdown list so you have 4 option to do that

- Customize your form via InfoPath as mentioned in this [viedo](https://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZx4SA3ZjOAhUoJcAKHa4HCsgQtwIIIjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DeSUSHsxsR6U&usg=AFQjCNFMwYT7NHAtWHGNc5vF4OeGtoETdw&sig2=pRUzAFYVlIDJaJ_KjWcSHA).
- Create a new cascading custom field as mentioned in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using).
- If you are using SharePoint 2010 you can use this solution at [complex](http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com/).
- Using the following `spservices` code and for more details check [this](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/02/cascading-dropdown-or-filtered-values.html).

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
>
> relationshipList: "Display Name of Master List",
>
> relationshipListParentColumn: 
>
> "Parent Column Internal Name from     Master List",
>
> relationshipListChildColumn: "Child Column Internal Name from Master List",
>
> parentColumn: "Parent Column Display Name from List/Library",
>
> childColumn: "Child Column Display Name from List/Library"
>
> });   
>
> });
> ```